# Расстановка знаков препинания, когда после прямой речи стоит деепричастный оборот

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

И сказал Господь: "Что ж вы делаете?" — видя, как Адам доедает голубя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После прямой речи ставится тире, если она заканчивается многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком:

*Я воротился, шагнул к ней и непременно б произнёс: «Сударыня!» — если бы только не знал, что это восклицание уже тысячу раз произносилось во всех русских великосветских романах* (Ф. Достоевский).
(**А: "П!" — а.** Тире после восклицательного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь.)

*Я только тогда выпрямился и подумал: «Зачем это отец ходит по саду?» — когда опять всё утихло вокруг* (И. Тургенев).
**(А: "П?" — а.** Тире после вопросительного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь.)

В Вашем предложении знаки препинания стоят правильно:
**И сказал Господь: "Что ж вы делаете?" — видя, как Адам доедает голубя.**

***Основную роль при постановке тире после прямой речи играет наличие в её конце вопросительного знака. Структура авторского предложения уже не имеет значения.***
Сравните (было бы так, с запятой, если бы не было знаков внутри прямой речи):

...шагнул к ней и непременно б произнёс: «Сударыня», если бы только не знал...
...выпрямился и подумал: «Отец ходит по саду», когда опять всё утихло вокруг.
**И сказал Господь: "Дурно делаете", видя, как Адам доедает голубя.**

[**Прямая речь внутри слов автора**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=442#pg442)